# Disable Seekbar/Progressbar from CastPlayer Notification (ExoPlayer)

Tags: android, chromecast, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using the ExoPlayer Cast Extension for playing an audio stream on a connected chromecast device.

The notification appears automatically when a Chromecast Session is connected.

How can i remove the progress bar from the notification? Could not find anything in the documentation.

[image: CastPlayer notification]

Answer (score 3):

Remove setMediaSession() from your MediaStyle().

Not using or assigning the token to mediaSession would mean that you won't have the controls you need to control your media service, also you loose feature like automatic setting of color(color temperature auto-detected from album-art) on your notification and would need to write custom indents for controlling the player.